# Couldn't save collection_radio_buttons in array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a problem to save the values of the radio_buttons of a loop. It doesn't save in an array. 
The SavedAnswer model has an has_and_belongs_to_many relation with the MultipleChoiceAnswer model.
This is my code:

```
<%= form_for @saved_answer do |f| %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= collection_radio_buttons(:saved_answer, :multiple_choice_answer_ids , question.multiple_choice_answers, :id, :title) do |c| %>
      <%= c.radio_button %>
      <%= c.label %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

My output is

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"57I9yLZMccvcb3Bn5/pw7kES0c9CUAGs33yCXoS0Urm1Yek/Baz8Hl7fO8Yl/OVZWLKsX7qrwOlqEBoXrGkcxQ==", "saved_answer"=>{ "multiple_choice_answer_ids"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have form_for with |f| and collection with |f|.
It's not a good decision, i think. That can cause problems. 
If not - write what you receive in params when trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

Just use check boxes for your issue:

```
<%= form_for @saved_answer do |f| %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "saved_answer[multiple_choice_answer_ids][]", question.id, @saved_answer.multiple_choice_answer_ids.include?(question.id) %>
    <%= question.title %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Refer: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast